# Illegal opcode error when attempting to create R package

Tags: r, compiler-errors, devtools, r-package, roxygen2

I'm writing an `R package` using `devtools` and `roxygen`.  Things have been going fine until recently, now, when I make some change and try to install the package again, I get an illegal `opcode error`.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong.  Typically I make changes to my package code, then do the following to update the changes:

```
library("devtools")
library("roxygen2")
setwd("/Path/To/R/myPackage")
document()
setwd("..")
install("myPackage")
```

The output looks like this:

```
> document()
Updating ciiDE documentation
Loading ciiDE
Writing NAMESPACE
Writing NAMESPACE
> setwd("..")
> install("ciiDE")
Installing ciiDE
Running command /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R 
Arguments:
CMD
INSTALL
/Path/To/R/myPackage
--library=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library
--install-tests

 *** caught illegal operation ***
address 0x7fffc2344ae4, cause 'illegal opcode'

Traceback:
 1: process_initialize(self, private, command, args, commandline,     stdout, stderr, cleanup, echo_cmd, windows_verbatim_args, windows_hide_window)
 2: .subset2(public_bind_env, "initialize")(...)
 3: process$new(command, args, commandline, echo_cmd = echo_cmd,     windows_verbatim_args = windows_verbatim_args, windows_hide_window = windows_hide_window,     stdout = "|", stderr = "|")
 4: run(bin, args = real_cmdargs, stdout_line_callback = real_callback(stdout),     stderr_line_callback = real_callback(stderr), stdout_callback = real_block_callback,     stderr_callback = real_block_callback, echo_cmd = echo, echo = show,     spinner = spinner, error_on_status = fail_on_status, timeout = timeout)
 5: force(code)
 6: with_envvar(env, run(bin, args = real_cmdargs, stdout_line_callback = real_callback(stdout),     stderr_line_callback = real_callback(stderr), stdout_callback = real_block_callback,     stderr_callback = real_block_callback, echo_cmd = echo, echo = show,     spinner = spinner, error_on_status = fail_on_status, timeout = timeout))
 7: eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
 8: eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
 9: with.default(options, with_envvar(env, run(bin, args = real_cmdargs,     stdout_line_callback = real_callback(stdout), stderr_line_callback = real_callback(stderr),     stdout_callback = real_block_callback, stderr_callback = real_block_callback,     echo_cmd = echo, echo = show, spinner = spinner, error_on_status = fail_on_status,     timeout = timeout)))
10: with(options, with_envvar(env, run(bin, args = real_cmdargs,     stdout_line_callback = real_callback(stdout), stderr_line_callback = real_callback(stderr),     stdout_callback = real_block_callback, stderr_callback = real_block_callback,     echo_cmd = echo, echo = show, spinner = spinner, error_on_status = fail_on_status,     timeout = timeout)))
11: run_r(options)
12: callr::rcmd_safe(..., env = env)
13: with_build_tools(callr::rcmd_safe(..., env = env), required = required)
14: pkgbuild::rcmd_build_tools("INSTALL", c(built_path, opts), echo = !quiet,     show = !quiet, fail_on_status = TRUE, required = FALSE)
15: install("myPackage")
```

I ran into this problem earlier and fixed it by updating my `devtools` and `roxygen` packages, but maybe that wasn't the fix at all.  **What can cause this sort of error?**  Am I updating my package incorrectly or something by using `install()` every time I modify the package code?

Any help is appreciated, having a bit of trouble with this one.

Comment: Reinstall some packages, and potentially R. This error means that R or a package is compiled for a different processor platform: its assembly code contains an opcode that your processor doesn’t understand (likely related to SSE).